# Broken linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, kde, oracle

Ever since I updated yesterday, the linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle has been full of trouble. First the Nvidia module would not load, after a lot of trial/error I was able to get the the 535 driver loaded to boot into the GUI. However the oracle kernel refuses to connect to the internet, load drivers or show the interfaces at all. I can log into the generic kernel and everything shows/works. Apt update/upgrade a few times and all is loaded. Below is everything I tried but still haven’t had success. USB’s will show, and I tried a usb ethernet adapter but I couldn’t find the realtek driver r8152 pre loaded. I defaulted to the generic kernel for now, tbh im not sure what I was running before or if it’s OK to run on generic over oracle. Any advice is appreciated.

```
Here are the drivers or packages I tried to install directly from a usb:
 inux-hwe-5.19-tools-common_5.19.0-50.50_all.deb linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.19.0-50-generic_5.19.0-50.50_amd64.deb linux-hwe-5.19-tools-5.19.0-50_5.19.0-50.50_amd64.deb linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-50-generic_5.19.0-50.50_amd64.deb linux-modules-5.19.0-1027-oracle_5.19.0-1027.30_amd64.deb

Booted into generic and re installed the kernel:
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle
sudo apt install linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle          jarvis@jarvis:~$ dkms status
nvidia/535.86.10, 5.19.0-1027-oracle, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.86.10, 5.19.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
paragon-uapfs/head, 5.19.0-1027-oracle, x86_64: installed
paragon-uapfs/head, 5.19.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
paragon-uapfs/head, 5.19.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
jarvis@jarvis:~$


Booted back into oracle:

jarvis@iarvis:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default glen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 br 00:00:00:00:00:00

sudo modprobe -r e1000e
sudo modprobe e1000e

Dmesg:
eth0 renamed from veth1f48745
eth0 Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
eth0 Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.

Added:
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X


sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager NetworkManager .service - Network Manager Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager. service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-08-01 09:42:12 EDT; 9s ago Docs: man: NetworkManager (8) Main PID: 6378 (NetworkManager) Tasks: 4 (limit: 76759) Memory: 3.9M CPU: 65ms CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager .service 16378 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.1740] device (br-7197496165c6): state change: secondaries -> activated (r Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.1741] device (br-7197496165c6): Activation: successful, device activated. Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [63781: <info> [1690897332.1742] device (br-80f1690cabcf): state change: secondaries - activated (r> Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [63781: <info> Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.17431 device (br-80f1690cabcf): Activation: successful, device activated. Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.1743] device (br-d8766844223): state change: secondaries - activated (r> Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.1744] device (br-d8766844223): Activation: successful, device activated. Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.17481 device (docker): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'no- Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <infos [1690897332.1749] device (docker): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason Aug 01 09:42:12 jarvis NetworkManager [6378]: <info> [1690897332.1750] device (docker): Activation: successful, device activated. ins Lines 1-21/21 (END) [1690897332.18811 manager: startup complete

Tried to add interface manually:

sudo nano /etc/netplan/eth0.yaml

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.50/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]


sudo netplan apply
```

Rebooted - Still nothing

Kubuntu 22.04
Software
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-50-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Hardware
Processors: 32 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ j9-13900KF
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2